# Bootstrap Affix Not Moving

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm trying to make the navigation sidebar on my website move down with the browser view via Bootstrap's Affix plugin however it refuses to follow the view and just stays at the top.

This is the structure I have for my HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="navigation-affix" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="20" data-offset-bottom="200">
                    <div class="col-xs-2" id="navigation-wrapper">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <img src="images/me.png" alt="Liam Potter" id="picture-me" class="img-responsive">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <div id="navigation">
                                        <a href="/" id="current-page">Home</a>
                                        <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-10" id="content-wrapper">
                    <div class="inner">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="page-push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="container">

        </div>
    </footer>
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/tbejd5en/1/

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you just use `position: fixed`?

Comment: Add `position:fixed` to your id `#navigation-affix` .. check this ... https://jsfiddle.net/tbejd5en/4/

Comment: @MinalChauhan that causes this to happen: http://i.imgur.com/URF2FLN.png

Comment: you need to add offset `col-xs-offset-2` to your id ` #content-wrapper` like this : `<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10" id="content-wrapper">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a `position:fixed` to your id `#navigation-affix` and add `col-xs-offset-2` to your id `#content-wrapper`

```
div#navigation-affix {
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tbejd5en/5/

Comment: This works however it requires me to hardcode the size of the sidebar which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a `position:fixed` to your id `#navigation`

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="/" id="current-page">Home</a>
            <a href="/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#navigation {
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/tbejd5en/2/

Comment: Sorry, by the navigation I meant the entire sidebar. Image and all. I can't seem to get it to work using position fixed for the entire sidebar.

Comment: In the [bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) they achieve this by using the bootstrap column for x positioning, and the inner element gets `position: fixed;`. So use a column for column layout, and create an inner div to contain everything you'd like to remain affixed.